# Is there a way to go through a set and on the same time adding items and iterate them also?

Tags: python, set, nfa

My first solution was this but it didn't work the way I exptected to. By this I mean that I wanted to add some item to this set and the set would be still able to iterate through the remained items and also the new item/s. For example if I have into e_closure_statesFinal the nums {2,3} and after the if statement the number 5 will be added I would want the first for loop to iterate through {2,3} and 5 also. Thanks in advance and sorry if I am not comprehensible.

```
for nextstate in e_closure_statesFinal:
        print(nextstate)
        for y in range(state,len(self.states)+ 1):
            if ((nextstate, '@') in self.transition_function.keys()):
               e_closure_statesFinal  = e_closure_statesFinal|self.transition_function[(nextstate, '@')]
            else :
                break
```

Second solution that worked but i want to know if there is a faster way.

```
 i = 0
    while i < len(e_closure_statesFinal):
    for nextstate in e_closure_statesFinal:
        for y in range(state,len(self.states)+ 1):
            if ((nextstate, '@') in self.transition_function.keys()):
                e_closure_statesFinal  = e_closure_statesFinal |self.transition_function[(nextstate, '@')]
                else :
            break
    i += 1
```

Comment: Normally this is solved with queues, where you prepopulate the queue with the initial elements, and pop things off the queue and add more things onto the queue while you process it. I'm not well versed in Python, so I'll just provide you with this link on queues in Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-queue-python-using-module-queue/. Using a queue will be more efficient than fully re-processing the list with an outer loop as in your and ShadowRanger's answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're specifically asking for cannot be done; modifying a `set` while iterating it is forbidden (even if it worked, the nature of Python's `set` is such that new elements could come before or after the ones already iterated, so it wouldn't be consistent, which is part of why this is forbidden). You could conceivably run a nested loop that ran over a copy of the original `set`, then ran over the difference between the resulting `set` and the original, etc. Something like:

```
workingset = {...}
lastset = set()
while lastset != workingset:  # Until a run doesn't change workingset
    newelems = workingset - lastset
    lastset = workingset.copy()
    for elem in newelems:  # Run over all new elements in workingset
        ... do stuff ...
        if somecondition:
             workingset.add(someelem)  # Maybe add stuff to workingset
```

Comment: Could you tell me that if your code will be faster than the second solution I used? I updated the main question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @M.Mar: I'd suggest testing, but your solution does have some red flags (in particular, it must do a full union to a new `set` for *every* hit on `if ((nextstate, '@') in self.transition_function.keys()):`, when only one is actually necessary, and in-place updates could be used for the others if not for the problem determining when you can safely do the operation in-place at all).